# integrating twitter feed into a shortcode for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, shortcode

I'm trying to create a simple shortcode for wordpress that has the following variables:
- username
- no_of_tweets

So a user could write [twitter_feed username="USERNAME" no_of_tweets="5"]

and it displays a list of 5 of their latest tweets. I have been using a plugin called Twitter Feed for developers - it does all the oAuth stuff and the idea is that you just write the code to output some front end html.

I have it working except for one annoying glitch - I can't get the no_of tweets to work.

This code works, but doesn't allow for users to specify the no_of_tweets variable:

```
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'username' => 'skizzar_sites',
            'no_of_tweets' => '3',
        ), $atts )
    );

    // Code
$tweets = getTweets(3, $username);
...
```

If I were tochange the code to the following (i.e. change the "3" in the $tweets variable, the code stops working:

```
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'username' => 'skizzar_sites',
        'no_of_tweets' => '5',
    ), $atts )
);

// Code
$tweets = getTweets($no_of_tweets, $username);
```

Is there any reason why this might not be working correctly?

See full code below:

```
<?php 
// Add Shortcode
function skizzar_twitter_feed( $atts ) {

// Attributes
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'username' => 'skizzar_sites',
        'no_of_tweets' => '5',
    ), $atts )
);

// Code
$tweets = getTweets($no_of_tweets, $username);//change number up to 20 for number of tweets
if(is_array($tweets)){

// to use with intents
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>';

foreach($tweets as $tweet){

if($tweet['text']){
    $the_tweet = $tweet['text'];

    if(is_array($tweet['entities']['user_mentions'])){
        foreach($tweet['entities']['user_mentions'] as $key => $user_mention){
            $the_tweet = preg_replace(
                '/@'.$user_mention['screen_name'].'/i',
                '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$user_mention['screen_name'].'" target="_blank">@'.$user_mention['screen_name'].'</a>',
                $the_tweet);
        }
    }


    if(is_array($tweet['entities']['hashtags'])){
        foreach($tweet['entities']['hashtags'] as $key => $hashtag){
            $the_tweet = preg_replace(
                '/#'.$hashtag['text'].'/i',
                '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23'.$hashtag['text'].'&src=hash" target="_blank">#'.$hashtag['text'].'</a>',
                $the_tweet);
        }
    }


    if(is_array($tweet['entities']['urls'])){
        foreach($tweet['entities']['urls'] as $key => $link){
            $the_tweet = preg_replace(
                '`'.$link['url'].'`',
                '<a href="'.$link['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$link['url'].'</a>',
                $the_tweet);
        }
    }

    echo $the_tweet;

    echo '
    <ul class="twitter_intents"> 
        <li><a class="reply" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='.$tweet['id_str'].'"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="retweet" href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='.$tweet['id_str'].'"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="favorite" href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='.$tweet['id_str'].'"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></li>
    </ul>';



    echo '
    <p class="timestamp">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/'.$username.'/status/'.$tweet['id_str'].'" target="_blank">
            '.date('h:i A M d',strtotime($tweet['created_at']. '- 8 hours')).'
        </a>
    </p>';// -8 GMT for Pacific Standard Time
} else {
    echo '
    <br /><br />
    <a href="http://twitter.com/'.$username.'" target="_blank">Click here to read '.$username.'\'S Twitter feed</a>';
}
}
}
}
add_shortcode( 'twitter_feed', 'skizzar_twitter_feed' );
```

Here is the getTweets function code:

```
/* implement getTweets */
function getTweets($username = false, $count = 20, $options = false) {

  $config['key'] = get_option('tdf_consumer_key');
  $config['secret'] = get_option('tdf_consumer_secret');
  $config['token'] = get_option('tdf_access_token');
  $config['token_secret'] = get_option('tdf_access_token_secret');
  $config['screenname'] = get_option('tdf_user_timeline');
  $config['cache_expire'] = intval(get_option('tdf_cache_expire'));
  if ($config['cache_expire'] < 1) $config['cache_expire'] = 3600;
  $config['directory'] = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);

  $obj = new StormTwitter($config);
  $res = $obj->getTweets($username, $count, $options);
  update_option('tdf_last_error',$obj->st_last_error);
  return $res;

}
```

Comment: Could you share the `getTweets` function code too?

Comment: @vard - added the code now

Comment: It seems that the order parameter you're sending is wrong. In function declaration the username is the first parameter, tweet count is the second, though you're calling it this way: `getTweets($no_of_tweets, $username)`

Comment: Aha!! Brilliant - how did I not notice that! Fixed it straight away! Thanks